# Find all the PDFs with at least three characters in their name

Tags: bash

I'd like to find the PDF files whose name (excluding the extension) is greater than three.

```
$ find ~  -iregex '.*/[^/]{3,}.pdf'
```

when test with

```
$ find ~ -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*/[^/]{3,}.pdf'
find: -regextype: unknown primary or operator
```

How can I enable the `{3,}` variant?

Comment: If this is GNU find, add the `-regextype posix-egrep` option. According to the [`info` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html), the default regex type is [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/emacs-regular-expression-syntax.html#emacs-regular-expression-syntax). I assume you can install GNU find with homebrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `find ~ -name '???*.pdf'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `-E` option with `find` or escape the curly brackets.

```
find -E ~ -iregex '.*/[^/]{3,}\.pdf'

find ~ -iregex '.*/[^/]\{3,\}\.pdf'
```

then escape the period .